# Order Statistics, Expected Value of range, $E(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})$

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, expected-value, order-statistics

$X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample from $U(0,\theta)$. Find $E(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})$.

I attempted this question by first finding the CDF of $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$ using the formula:
$$F_{U}(u)= n\int_0^\theta f(x)[F(u+x)-F(x)]^{n-1}dx$$
Where $U=X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$, $f(x)$ is the PDF of $U(0,\theta)$ and $F(x)$ is the CDF of $U(0,\theta)$.

Using this formula I obtained:
$$F_{U}(u)=n\frac{u^{n-1}}{\theta^{n-1}}$$

Now, using the following formula for non-negative continuous random variables:
$$E(U) = \int_0^\theta (1-F_{U}(u))du$$

I obtained:
$$E(U) = \int_0^\theta \Big(1-n \Big(\frac{u}{\theta}\Big)^{n-1}\Big)du=\theta - \frac{n}{\theta^{n-1}}\Big[\frac{u^n}{n}\Big]_{0}^{\theta}=\theta-\theta=0$$

However, if I break the expectation and calculate individually,
$$E(U) = E(X_{(n)})-E(X_{(1)})$$
I get the answer as:
$$E(U) = \frac{n-1}{n+1}\theta$$ which I believe is the right answer. Can someone please explain why is the former method giving an incorrect answer?

EDIT:
Proof of CDF of $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$. (General case when $X_{i}$'s are defined over the range $(-\infty,\infty))$

[image: Proof of CDF of $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$. (General case when $X_{i}$'s are defined over the range $(-\infty,\infty))$]

[image]

Comment: Where is the formula from? I don't recognize it.

Comment: @Greenparker Here is a link to the page (formula no. 10) giving the joint pdf of $X_{(1)},X_{(n)}$: [link](http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/OrderStatistics.html). I have then just used tranformations to get the CDF of $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$. I will also add my workings in the question.

Comment: @Greenparker The proof is a bit long-winded and my $Latex$ skills are not that good. I think I will just upload a picture of my workings.

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud, but is there a reason you didn't just use the linearity of expectation to parcel out $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}\right)$ as $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{(n)}\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(X_{(1)}\right)$?

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa I just wanted to try an alternate method to solve the problem. Thought that this method might be a bit simpler than calculating the individual expectations.

Comment: Let $\theta=1$. Distribute $n+1$ points uniformly around a *circle* of unit diameter. Pick one of them as a place to cut the circle. Call it $x_0$ and let the rest be $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in positive order. The remaining $n$ values are uniform on the resulting unit interval. The range, plus the *positive* distance from $x_n$ back to $x_1$ on the circle, equals $1$. The expectation of that distance is the sum of expected distances between two neighbors, $x_n,x_0$ and $x_0,x_1$. Both those expectations equal $1/(n+1)$ (because $n+1$ of them sum to $1$). Thus the expected range is $1-2/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the joint distribution $(X_{(n)}, X_{(1)})$ and you need to find the distribution of $X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$. From the link you provided

$$ f_{1,n}(x,y)  = n(n- 1) \dfrac{(y-x)^{n-2}}{\theta^{n-2}} \dfrac{1}{\theta^2}.$$

Let $y-x$ = $u$

$$ f_{1,n}(x,x+u)  = n(n- 1) \dfrac{u^{n-2}}{\theta^{n-2}} \dfrac{1}{\theta^2}.$$

Now, I integrate out $x$
$$f_U(u) = \int_0^{\theta - u} n(n- 1) \dfrac{u^{n-2}}{\theta^{n-2}} \dfrac{1}{\theta^2} dx = n(n-1) \dfrac{u^{n-2}}{\theta^{n}} (\theta - u) $$

Now, 
\begin{align*}
E(U) &= n(n-1) \int u  \dfrac{u^{n-2}}{\theta^{n}}(\theta - u) du\\
& = \dfrac{n(n-1)}{\theta^{n}} \int u^{n-1}(\theta - u) du\\
& = \dfrac{n(n-1)}{\theta^{n}} \dfrac{\theta^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}\\
& = \theta\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}
\end{align*}

I think your mistake was in finding the density for the range.

Comment: Just to follow-up, how would finding the expectation change if the range of U was -theta,theta. My current joint pdf of the range is very large and not sure if I am correct.